# How to use UPSTART feature of ubuntu to restart the python script but not as root?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart

I am running my Python script using upstart feature of Ubuntu so that if for whatever reason my Python script dies or gets killed, it can be restarted automatically and everything is working fine -

So I decided to use `UPSTART` feature of Ubuntu to restart the Python script automatically.

After creating the `testing.conf` file like this in `/etc/init/testing.conf` -

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

chdir /tekooz
respawn

post-stop script
  sleep 30
end script

exec python testing.py
```

I ran below sudo command to start it and I can see that process running using `ps ax` and my python script is also running fine. And when I check the pid of the above process, I always see it is running as root. I don't want to run that as root. Instead I want to run that as `deds` account

```
deds@bx13:/$ sudo start testing
testing start/running, process 3635
deds@bx13:/$ ps aux | grep testing
root      3635  2.4  0.1 364136 15660 ?        Ssl  12:24   0:00 python testing.py
```

Is there some other place where I need to put the `testing.conf` file and then run it with some other command?

I don't want to start my python script by doing `sudo` as `sudo start testing` and also I don't want to start as root, I just want to start as `deds` account. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: You can try the method in the Upstart docs here: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-as-a-different-user

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. If your upstart version (use the `initctl --version` command) is at least 1.4, then add the following lines to your testing.conf file:

```
setuid deds
setgid deds
```

otherwise, change your `exec` line to:

```
exec sudo -u deds python testing.py
```